# Unexpected token error when parsing JSX file

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs, eslint

Am getting the below error in my main.js file when using ESLint and babel

main.js

```
const mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
function HelloMessage(props) {
  return <div>Hello {props.name}</div>;
}
render(<HelloMessage name="test" />, mountNode);
```

Error is

```
Unexpected token (12:10) while parsing file: c:\Dev\...\src\main.js
```

which points to the line

```
return <div>Hello {props.name}</div>;
```

I have enabled ES6 and JSX in ESLint config

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
```

Also, .babelrc has the presets defined

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error finally went away by adding the below to my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "transform-export-extensions"
  ]
}
```

Ofcourse this required the following npm packages to be installed

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions
```

Thanks